# working with nodes in a webshop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning on making a custom shop for a store that has products with subproducts with prices that depend on the number of orders...

So, I'm thinking of working with nodes where there will basically be 1 huge table of data connected to each other by the parent and id values

```
- node type="product" value="productname"
    - node type="subproduct" value="specification_1"
        - node type="price_per_piece" value="1000"
            - node type="price" value="13$"
        - node type="price_per_piece" value="2000"
            - node type="price" value="12$"
        - node type="price_per_piece" value="3000"
            - node type="price" value="11$"
        - node type="price_per_piece" value="4000"
            - node type="price" value="10$"

    - node type="subproduct" value="specification_2"
    - node type="subproduct" value="specification_3"
    - node type="subproduct" value="specification_4"
```

I haven't type them but every node is supposed to have a unique number, this way I can backtrace the order if I have the final node.

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid mixing different types of data in a single table.

I would create a table for each type of entity(category/product/etc) without any structure information and create additional tables to hold any kind of structure relations that my be needed(could be categories/tags/related product). This way you can also easily have multiple parents for a product.

For varying specification fields(if it can't be plain text) for different types of products and such, I would store those as serialized php arrays.